# Is it possible to access the actual heat flux transmitted via a 'surface film condition' in ABAQUS?

Tags: output, post-processing, abaqus

I have defined surfaces on my model on which I have applied a 'surface film condition' with a sink temperature profile and a film coefficient profile for a transient thermal simulation to model heating/cooling of the surface via convection.

In which ways can I access the heat flux / total amount of heat which is transmitted via this interaction during the simulation? Since the model contains a number of different surfaces and interactions, the easier the solution is, the better. As I recall LS-DYNA for example outputs this automatically.

Helpful solutions or advice on where to search are gratefully accepted, as I have not found anything in the documentation or on the web. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two lines at the end of the output section in the .inp file. Did not found a way to do it in CAE, so you have to do it manually in the input file.

```
 *SECTION PRINT, NAME=Section-Name, SURFACE=Surface_name
 SOH,
```

From the Documentation:

> SOH - Total heat flux across the section.

Comment: SOH is the second line